# Find a polynomial $q(x)$ of minimal degree in $F_3[x]$ so that the following condition is true:

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, quotient-spaces, chinese-remainder-theorem

$q(x)\equiv x ~(\text{mod}(x^2+2))$

$q(x) \equiv 1 (\text{mod} ~x)$

$q(x) \equiv (x+1) (\text{mod} (x^2 + 2x + 2))$

I know that this is a question about the Chinese remainder theorem but I have no idea how to do it with polynomials!

Should I first add up all the mods ?

Comment: You don’t add the moduli, any more than you do when using CRT for integers.

Comment: I get q(x) = P1(x)(x^2+2x+2) + P2 (x^2+2)(x^2+2x+2) + P3 (x^2+2)(x). But I don't know how to find P1, P2 and P3!

Comment: The polynomial should be of degree $\leq 2$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you could use Chinese Remainder, but since the moduli are not exactly independent, I would just look at it with a piercing eye and see what’s what.

The second requirement, $q\equiv1\pmod x$, simply says that your polynomial has constant term $1$, or in other words that $q(0)=1$. The first requirement requires that $q\equiv x\pmod{x^2-1}$. (Remember that you’re in characteristic three, where $2=-1$.) Since any multiple of $x^2-1$ vanishes at $\pm1$, the condition $q\equiv x\pmod{x^2-1}$ says that $q$ has the same value at $1$ and $-1$ as $x$ does. So the two first conditions specify $q(0)=1$, $q(1)=1$, and $q(-1)=-1$. Surely no degree-one polynomial can satisfy this, and you know that three values determine a parabola. I’ll leave that to you.